# SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I have an application, which would send file to other installed application. I am using FileProvider to do it.

Its working fine in 4.2, but the real problem is in 2.3 mobiles.

This is my provider.

```
<provider
            android:name="com.example.sample.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.sample.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths" />
        </provider>
```

And I had few suggestions in stackoverflow, by setting exported="true". But FileProvider doesn't allow to attach provider, if it so.

When the other application access the `Uri`, the app crash with following message.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.example.sample.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{4079bd68 5637:com.google.android.apps.docs/10060} (pid=5637, uid=10060) requires null or null
```

The `Intent` is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please help me with this.

**Edit 1:**
I am trying to send a text file by forming uri: `content://com.example.sample.provider/my_docs/sample.txt`
to google drive app.

Here's the drive application crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.example.sample.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{406e05a8 6502:com.google.android.apps.docs/10060} (pid=6502, uid=10060) requires null or null
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:1882)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getProvider(ActivityThread.java:3499)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:3524)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1712)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:757)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:328)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at rL.a(UriDataSource.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at rE.a(ItemToUpload.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at aDW.a(ExtraStreamDataSource.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at com.google.android.apps.docs.shareitem.UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.a(UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at aEk.a(UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.java:811)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at aEk.doInBackground(UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6502):    ... 4 more
```

Thanks,

Boopathy.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: What paths have you defined in your paths.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on Android 2.3 devices. The only solution is setting the android:exported attribute to "true" on Android 2.3, implementing our own FileProvider class (copy the source of FileProvider to your package) and disabling the exported flag checking, check FileProvider.attachInfo(), when running on Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use FileProvider from support library?

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" ... />
```